# How to find the area between two curves

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Find the area between `y = 1 - x/π` and `y = Sin[x]`.

Here is what I have typed in so far into *Mathematica*:

```
Clear[f, g, x]
f[x_] := 1 - x/π
g[x_] := Sin[x]
Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, 0, 2 π}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, PlotRange -> {-1.2, 1.2}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

The graph worked, so I have that. However, when I try to do the next step,
`Solve[f[x] = g[x], x]`, it will not give me the intersects. I have even tried retyping the equations in: `Solve[Sin[x] = 1 - x/π, x]`, but nothing is working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Alison. You need to use `Pi` (not pi), and `==` (not =). And try specifying `Reals` for `Solve`'s domain. (Although that might not be the real problem.) And I wonder, section 6.1 of what?

Comment: Works for me with `Solve[f[x] == g[x], x, Reals]`.

Comment: The real problem is that it is a trancedental equation and no analytical solutions to these types of equations are known in general (though the x=Pi solution can be readily seen here). Try `NSolve` instead for a numerical solution.

Comment: FYI you can just integrate the thing without explicitly finding the roots.. `Integrate[Abs[f[x] - g[x]], {x, 0, 2 Pi}] // N`

Comment: @george2079, I wrote this answer with little more explanation.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
Plot[Abs[f[x] - g[x]], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Filling->Axis]
```

should convince you that this measures the high between the two curves (*), regardless of which one is at the top. So, as pointed already by @george2079, use `NIntegrate` like

```
NIntegrate[Abs[f[x] - g[x]], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

**%=** 2.43935

(*) Note that *Mathematica* has powerful integration mechanisms, but you need to gain insight in what you are doing to unleash its power. `Abs` is a measure of magnitude in the real line and that's why is being used above.